# Digital Rights Management in Umbraco

Tags: pdf, umbraco, drm

I have an Umbraco website and I want to share some PDF files on it. However, I also want to ensure that no one can copy the content of these files - to the extent that even print screen button doesnt work when someone wants to print the screen displaying those PDFs. I know there is a software Copysafe - https://www.copysafe.net/ which prevents screenshots of the page. I have two questions:

- Is there any way I can display PDFs and prevent someone from copying my data (disabling PrtScr button, watermarks etc) using Umbraco out of box functionality or some simple development work?
- Is there any add on that Umbraco has which will help me use copysafe functionality on my website?

Thanks for reading my question and hope you could help :)

Comment: I'd guess that PDF's are typically protected during creation, not after being uploaded to somewhere? But no, there's nothing built in to Umbraco that can do it out of the box. And I've never heard of a plug-in/add-on/package that can do it either, sorry :-/

Comment: I think you need to protect access to the files - login to that area of your site, request people to supply details etc. 
By it's nature, if you "share some files" - then you have shared them - and how they are viewed/shared further is out of your control.